# Trouble with query with two tables

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have following two tables (here with random data)

```
 cu                         cgm
+-----+---------+-----+    +---------+--------+
| uid | name    | ... |    | groupid | userid |
+-----+---------+-----+    +---------+--------+
|   1 | manfred | ... |    |       2 |      2 |
|   2 | peter   | ... |    |       2 |      5 |
|   3 | jackson | ... |    |       2 |      7 |
| ... |  ...    | ... |    |       4 |      3 |
+-----+---------+-----+    +---------+--------+
  uid <========= FOREIGN KEY ========== userid
```

I want to select `cu.name` and `cu.uid` / `cgm.userid` by `cgm.groupid` and put the values into an associative array where the keys are `cu.name` and the values `cu.uid` / `cgm.userid`. My only solution was to send a query to select `cgm.userid` by `cgm.groupid`, send a second query to select `cu.name` by `cu.uid` and put the data together. But I was wondering, if there is way to achieve this with only one query and use PHP as less as possible.

Comment: what you mean by `/` is a division or a comma ?

Comment: "/" means "or", because `cu.uid` and `cgm.userid` hold the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cu.name, cu.uid FROM cu LEFT JOIN cgm ON cu.uid = cgm.userid WHERE cgm.groupid = 2
```

You can adjust `WHERE` condition to your needs.

Comment: Thanks you. But I don't fully understand `ON`. Is it a condition for connecting the datasets from `cu` with `cgm`?

Comment: it is the equivalent of `WHERE x = y` but for the join - e.g. `join cgm ON cu.uid = cgm.userid -- equiv of WHERE cu.uid = cgm.userid`

Comment: By JOIN you tell MySQL to attach another table to the results and by ON you tell exact how to do this, so ON tells how to bind data from first dataset with those in secont one.

It's short explanation but you really should go to link that @scrowler provided so you can understand joining tabels better.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL with a LEFT JOIN could be:

```
SELECT cu.name, cu.uid, cgm.userid, cgm.userid, cgm.groupid
FROM cu
LEFT JOIN cgm ON cu.uid = cgm.userid
WHERE cgm.groupid = 2 -- your var there
```

Although you don't need to select `cgm.userid` in this case as it should be the same as `cu.uid` (if it's not, this join isn't correct).

With PHP:

```
$group_id = 2;
$sql = "SELECT ..... WHERE cgm.groupid = " . $group_id;
$query = $db->query($sql); // your query functions here...
```

[To help you avoid SQL injection, your should bind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2812842) `$group_id` as a parameter:

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT ... WHERE cgm.groupid = :group_id");
$sth->bindParam(':group_id', $group_id, PDO::PARAM_INT); // only accept integers
$sth->execute();
```

**More info:**

- SQL Joins: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
- PDO binding: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by using join. Use below query.

```
select uid,name from cu,cgm where uid=userid and groupid =<GROUP_ID>;
```

You can use PDO to connect your database.

```
$conn= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=chatting4u','root','');
    $stmt=$conn->prepare('select uid,name from cu,cgm where uid=userid and groupid =<GROUP_ID>');
    $stmt->execute();
    $row=$stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now you will get uid, uname in $row array. Try it,i hope it will work.

References:-

Databse Joins-> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

PDO in PHP-> http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: That is not exactly what I wanted. I wanted to select `uid` and `name` by `groupid`

Comment: yup. i missed that. check my modified answer. replace <group_id> with your desired value.